# my application crash in ListView Event orThread

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

```
lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,int position, long id) {
    //btnsub is button
    btnsub.setEnabled(true); 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "before start()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
        //lst is ListView Object
        View vtmp = lst.getChildAt(i);
        if(vtmp !=null){
        if(i==lst.getCheckedItemPosition()){
            //cindex is int var
            cindex=lst.getCheckedItemPosition();
            }else{  }
        }
    }

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in Thread ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    lst.getChildAt(cindex).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }catch(Exception e){
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thread Generate: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    }.start();


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "after start()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 });
```

Comment: Toast in thread is wrong. Show toast on the ui thread. ALso setting background color. Why do you need thread in the first place?? and do post the stacktrace

Comment: i have set listView Item background color directly in if condition but this not work properly thats why i used Thread any other option then suggest me...

Comment: Try to change item background when particular item CheckBox checked change at adapter getView(). with CheckBox check change listener.

Comment: Heyy mr @Prasathviki I have try to your suggestion instead of thread but it is not working properly

Comment: Mr.Haresh i have not understand your answer

Comment: Mr @user3744544 i cant understand your question. Crash occurs in which line.

Comment: Thank you @yushulx your solution properly working

Answer (score 0):

You can't update UI in worker thread. Modify your code:

```
new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in Thread ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                lst.getChildAt(cindex).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
             }
            });
            }catch(Exception e){

                }
            }
    }.start();
```

A better way is to use Handler, you can read - [Communicating with the UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the thread part by below code :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                        public void run() {
                                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in Thread ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    lst.getChildAt(cindex).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }catch(Exception e){
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thread Generate: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
                        }
                    });
```